# How should I write this method?

Tags: ruby, methods

The question's prompt is:

> Write a method that takes an array of numbers. If a pair of numbers in the array sums to zero, return the positions of those two numbers. If no pair of numbers sums to zero, return `nil`.

I'm not sure how to approach this problem and what would be the simplest way. Would this involve the .index method?

```
def two_sum(nums)
end

two_sum([1,3,5,-3])
```

Comment: My ideas so far were to add all the possible pairs in the array, and then if any of the pairs == 0, I would return the indices of those numbers. But I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: Remember that adding "b" and "a" is the same as adding "a" and "b", so you only have to do half that work.

Comment: here's a hint: no temp array is needed. Just two loops.

Comment: I'm wracking my brain and still can't do it!

Comment: Well, if the array is large enough it would be more correct to use a temp array.

Comment: Maybe you can ask for every item on the list if exist his negative, and if it exists...

Comment: @Ajedi32 For arbitrarily large data sets sorting would be faster. You have to  store the original position in some way, such as a temp array.

Comment: If `a = [1,1,1,1,1]`, do you want `[0,1]` or `[1,2]` or `[2,3]` or `[0,4]`, or do you want `[[0,1],[2,3]]` or `[[1,2],[3,4]]` or...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with a lot of things in Ruby, there are a couple different ways of doing this. The "classic" approach to this problem would be to use two nested loops:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  for i1 in 0...nums.length
    for i2 in i1...nums.length
      # Inside this loop, nums[i1] represents one number in the array
      # and nums[i2] represents a different number.
      #
      # If we find that the sum of these numbers is zero...
      if nums[i1] + nums[i2] == 0
        # Then we have our answer
        return i1, i2
      end
    end
  end

  # At this point we've checked every possible combination and haven't
  # found an answer, so a pair of numbers that sum to zero in that array
  # must not exist. Return nil.
  nil
end
```

The other approach uses Ruby magic to do the same thing in a somewhat more expressive way:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  result_pair = nums.each_with_index.to_a.combination(2).find{|n1, n2| n1.first + n2.first == 0}
  result_pair && result_pair.map(&:last)
end
```

The breakdown here is a bit more complex. If you'd like to understand it, I recommend looking at the documentation for these methods on [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html) and [`Enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html).

Comment: Expressive way version is very nice

Comment: I keep getting an error with your first code. The `if nums[i1] + nums[i2] == 0` statement is causing me some trouble

Comment: @Shawn Shawn. Oops sorry, off-by-one error. Guess I don't use `for` loops very often in Ruby. Anyway, should be fixed now.

Comment: @Ajedi32 you rarely need to use **for** in ruby

Comment: @Ajedi32 I really like the expressive way of doing this as well. Could you explain why in the 3rd line you write `result_pair && result_pair.map(&:last)`? Wouldn't `result_pair.map(&:last)` suffice?

Comment: @Shawn The previous line returns `nil` if no matches are found. Calling `map` on nil would result in an error, so we take advantage of short circuit evaluation here to ensure that `result_pair` is not nil before attempting to call `map` on it. Rails has a nice method called `try` built for dealing with that problem, but you can't use it outside of Rails without loading ActiveSupport.

Comment: Method #1: `two_sum [0] #=> [0, 0] `.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do this:

```
def two_sum(nums)
  seen = {}
  nums.each_with_index do |n, i| 
    return seen[-1*n], i if seen.key?(-1*n)
    seen[n] = i
  end
  nil
end
```

It's faster that the above (you do it in one pass) so O(n). 
It does use O(n) additional space compared to the naive approach that checks each element against each element (but that one's O(n^2)

Answer (score 0):

This returns offsets for all pairs of values that sum to zero. The return value is not unique, however. If, for example, `a = [1,1,1,-1,-1]`, pairs summing to zero might be at offsets `[[0,3],[1,4]]` or `[[1,3],[2,4]]` or other values.

**Code**

```
def match_zero_sums(arr)
  h = arr.each_with_index.group_by(&:first)
  h.keys.select { |k| k >= 0 }.each_with_object([]) do |k,a|
    while (k==0 && h[k].size > 1) || (k>0 && h[k].any? && h[-k].any?)
      a << [h[k].shift.last, h[-k].shift.last]
    end if h.key?(-k)
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = [2,3,0,0,-2,-3,4,-3,0,3]
match_zero_sums(arr)
  #=> [[0, 4], [1, 5], [9, 7], [2, 3]]
```

**Explanation**

For `arr` in the example:

```
enum0 = arr.each_with_index
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2, 3, 0, 0, -2, -3, 4, -3, 0, 3]:each_with_index> 
h = enum0.group_by(&:first)
  #=> { 2=>[[2, 0]], 3=>[[3, 1], [3, 9]], 0=>[[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 8]],
  #    -2=>[[-2, 4]], -3=>[[-3, 5], [-3, 7]], 4=>[[4, 6]]} 
non_neg_keys = h.keys.select { |k| k >= 0 }
  #=> [2, 3, 0, 4]
enum1 = non_neg_keys.each_with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: [2, 3, 0, 4]:each_with_object([])> 
k,a = enum1.next
  #=> [2, []] 
k #=> 2 
a #=> [] 
h.key?(-k)
  #=> h.key?(-2) => true
```

so execute the `while` loop:

```
k==0 && h[k].size > 1
  #=> 2==0 && h[2].size > 1
  #=> false && true => false
k>0 && h[k].any? && h[-k].any?
  #=> 2>0 && h[2].any? && h[-2].any?
  #=> true && true && true => true
false || true #=> true
```

so compute:

```
a << [h[k].shift.last, h[-k].shift.last]
  #=> a << [h[2].shift.last, h[-2].shift.last]
  #=> a << [[2,0].last, [-2,4].last]
  #=> a << [0,4]
```

so now:

```
a #=> [[0,4]]
```

and

```
h #=> { 2=>[], 3=>[[3, 1], [3, 9]], 0=>[[0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 8]],
  #    -2=>[], -3=>[[-3, 5], [-3, 7]], 4=>[[4, 6]]}
```

The remaining calculations are similar.

Answer (score 0):

As always, there are usually many ways to solve a problem, especially with Ruby. If you had come from another language like Java or Python, there is a great chance you might not be already familiar with the `each_with_index` or `each.with_index` methods. Without over complicating the solution, just break the problem down into two separate while loops, and return the indexes of the pair that equates to zero if it exists. Ruby provides many methods to make life much easier, but without knowing the majority of them, you'll still be able to solve a plethora of problems with a solid foundation of the basics of programming.

```
def two_sum(nums)
  i = 0
  while i < nums.length
    j = 0
    while j < nums.length
      if nums[i] + nums[j] == 0
        return i, j
      end
      j += 1
    end
    i += 1
  end
  return nil
end`
```